# How do I properly escape double-quotes when sending HTML from Applescript into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

I am working on an Applescript script which executes some Javascript to add some HTML to a webpage I am viewing on my local machine. Applescript is reading the HTML file into a string and automatically escapes all the double quotes in the HTML like this: \"

But Javascript doesn't like the string with all the escaped double-quotes in it:

set programHTML to "\"Hi kid!\"" --This works!

set programHTML to "\"Hi \"kid!\"" --This doesn't!

I feel like I must be missing something very basic here. I scanned and skimmed many posts but have not seen anything addressing this specific problem.

[Adding this after what would have been a helpful comment had I been a bit more explicit]:

Nothing with more than the quotes on the end works when it gets to Javascript. This does not work:

set programHTML to "\"Howdy, \"kid!\", is your \"Mom\" home?\""

I should perhaps mention that this string is going into a line which looks something like this:

execute tab 1 of front window javascript "codeDIV.innerHTML = " & programHTML & ";"

Answer (score 2):

Double Quotes must always be used in **pair**. that's why your second method does not works.

set programHTML to ***"\"Hi kid!\"" --This works!***

-- Because it results in `"Hi kid"` - 2 double quotes

set programHTML to ***"\"Hi \"kid!\"" --This doesn't!***

Because it results in `"Hi "kid!"` - 3 double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Change the outer quotes to single quotes so they don't interfere with the inner double quotes. If you do this, you don't need to worry about escaping the double quotes at all.

```
//using the single quote in the beginning and end
console.log('"Howdy, "kid!", is your "mom" home?"');
```

reads as "Howdy, "kid!", is your "mom" home?"